# Is it possible to use a Regular Expression to extract different blocks of text and multiple lines?

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to extract different blocks of text from a report document using a regular expression - each new page is denoted with \x0c in front of "FIRST NOTICE" [not shown below].  I have included a picture w/ line numbers as well as the text though the formatting may be an issue.

The report text will contain 1..n pages - each being a separate line item when the data is returned.  This data will be extracted and turned into rows to be entered into a database [Number, Balance, Name, Address1, Address2, City, State, Zip].

The pieces of data that I need to extract:

1. NUMBER - 11-1-11111-1
2. BALANCE - 1000.00
3. Name - "DOEN, JOHN THOMAS" [line 14, col 7-50]
4. Address - 2 to 3 lines
5. Further - broken into Addr1/Addr2/City/State/Zip
6. The line with city:  City ST Zip4 or Zip-9
7. City could contain spaces

The number and balance are relatively easy to acquire - it's the name and address section that I am having the most issue with and am looking for a single regex that will pull each item into its own group.

The address is on lines 15-17 and columns 7-50.

Is this even possible ?

**Sample document containing two pages:**

[image]

```
 FIRST NOTICE                         COMPANYNAME
 NOTICE DATE....: 01/01/2001          1111 N NORTHWOOD DR
 NUMBER.........: 11-1-11111-1        SOMEWHERE WY 05920-5929
 THE DATE.......: 02/01/2001

 Some data only.







      DOEN, JOHN THOMAS                           ORIGINAL....:      5789.00
      1111 N WALT AVE                             BALANCE.....:      1000.00
      C/O SOMEONE ELSE                            PAST DUE....:       500.00
      SOMEWHERE WY 04741-5555

 THIS IS THE END OF THIS PAGE                     DATE DUE: 02/01/2001
 FIRST NOTICE                         COMPANYNAME
 NOTICE DATE....: 01/01/2001          1111 N NORTHWOOD DR
 NUMBER.........: 22-2-22222-2        SOMEWHERE WY 05920-5929
 THE DATE.......: 02/01/2001

 Some data only.







      DOE, JOHNAT ZOAR                            ORIGINAL....:      2211.00
      11111 N DIVISOR RD                          BALANCE.....:      2000.00
      SOMWEHERE WY 05922                          PAST DUE....:      1000.00


 THIS IS THE END OF THIS PAGE                     DATE DUE: 02/01/2001
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. I learned regex about 2 years into learning programming. Everyone should learn it instead of asking someone else every time. It's not that hard once you get the hang of it.

Comment: That's what Stack Overflow is for, and not for insulting someone and assuming that they are "asking someone else every time".  I know how to research, and have - and was not able to find anything like this.  I know Regex but this, in my opinion is an advanced question.  If you think it's possible, then proffer a solution.

Comment: @AndreasMüller A ridiculous comment, SO is so developers can help each other. There would be no need for this site with your approach!

Comment: @Matthew M. up/downvoting is dependant on research effort. I appreciate your well put samples but i can't see the research effort yet(the regex you tried).

from just a brief look your regex has to be something like FIRST NOTICE empty space (text until newline)
NOTICE DATE... (Date) empty space (alphanumeric till newline). Not really very advanced in my opinion.

You can trust me it's not meant as insult, but as a general note - you may not notice how many people post questions on SO who apparently never read up on anything they ask questions for.

Comment: @Jaycee Yes. So they can help each other. Not so they can do the work of others. Usually you see me posting SO question after debugging a couple of days, a behaviour i can't explain to myself or until i have no idea left to try. That's the way to go unless you want to ask rather simple to answer questions...

Comment: @AndreasMüller Look at the text - "The number and balance are easy to acquire - it's the name and address section that I am having the most issue with" - Why would I post my trials and experiments ?  I formulated a question, took the time to make sure the sample data was adequate, and am asking the larger community a question hoping that someone has the answer that I'm seeking.

Comment: @AndreasMüller Again, if this is such a simple task, answer the question and I'll be happy to award you the green check.  In my opinion, it's not my responsibility to detail every step I took or who I conferred with.  Someone else may be looking for this same issue - I couldn't find anything that came close to this.  Additionally, I wrote my own parser to solve this issue - but I'm wondering if it can be done with a single regex [simpler!] statement.  If it gets answered, then that knowledge is preserved and will help someone else in the future.

Comment: @AndreasMüller I understand the point about research effort except it is all relative. A first year student may have tried everything he knows and failed in what an experienced programmer would find easy. I suspect you might criticise them though.

Comment: Fair enough. Looking at this when i'm at home, unless it's solved by then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex explicitly supports multiline as below

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"pattern1|pattern2", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var matches = reg.Matches("my text with /n lines");
```

Another aspect of Regex is that you can partition your pattern into segments which amounts to alternate text to match on. See this article on the [vertical bar](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Using the MatchCollection returned from reg.Matches you will be able to extract your data.

I would suggest matching on the name and address lines individually, If you can always rely on the string ORIGINAL being to the right on the same line as the name for example, then you can write the regex for that separately. The regex engine will match on the patterns in order but you need some anchor text to search for clearly and then get the value relative to the anchor text. You would then need to parse and clean the returned value from the Match object

**UPDATE** 
**My previous answer partly edited to remove extraneous info**

Below is a program containing a solution, the Regex is relatively straightforward so I will just break that down for those not familiar with the syntax for the first pattern:

```
^[A-Z, ]+(?=original...)|^[A-Z, 0-9]+(?=balance...)|^[//A-Z, 0-9]+(?=past due...)|^[^\n\.]{2,50}(?=\n\s+\n^\s+THIS IS THE END OF THIS PAGE)
```

The regex contains 4 separate patterns split by `|` which means alternation.

*You can test the pattern [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester) being careful not to add any extra characters and ensuring you check the multiline and ignore case options.*

`^` captures the start of a line as we are using multiline mode via the Regex constructor

`[A-Z, ]` captures A-Z, a comma and a space

`+` repeat occurrences of preceding token 1 or more times equivalent of saying `{1,}`

`(?=original....)` lookahead for the pattern in this case `original....`hence(?=*pattern*)

[The lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) does not capture characters but just matches.

The other patterns are similar though the last one matches a couple of blank lines before the anchor THIS IS THE END OF THIS PAGE and sets a min/max occurrences on some characters `{2,50}`

C# sample which cleans the tokens returned - name and address - 7 items for the example data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegexTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static string text = @"FIRST NOTICE                         COMPANYNAME
 NOTICE DATE....: 01/01/2001          1111 N NORTHWOOD DR
 NUMBER.........: 11-1-11111-1        SOMEWHERE WY 05920-5929
 THE DATE.......: 02/01/2001

 Some data only.







      DOEN, JOHN THOMAS                           ORIGINAL....:      5789.00
      1111 N WALT AVE                             BALANCE.....:      1000.00
      C/O SOMEONE ELSE                            PAST DUE....:       500.00
      SOMEWHERE WY 04741-5555

 THIS IS THE END OF THIS PAGE                     DATE DUE: 02/01/2001
 FIRST NOTICE                         COMPANYNAME
 NOTICE DATE....: 01/01/2001          1111 N NORTHWOOD DR
 NUMBER.........: 22-2-22222-2        SOMEWHERE WY 05920-5929
 THE DATE.......: 02/01/2001

 Some data only.







      DOE, JOHNAT ZOAR                            ORIGINAL....:      2211.00
      11111 N DIVISOR RD                          BALANCE.....:      2000.00
      SOMWEHERE WY 05922                          PAST DUE....:      1000.00


 THIS IS THE END OF THIS PAGE                     DATE DUE: 02/01/2001";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern = @"^[A-Z, ]+(?=original...)|^[A-Z, 0-9]+(?=balance...)|^[//A-Z, 0-9]+(?=past due...)|^[^\n\.]{2,50}(?=\n\s+\n^\s+THIS IS THE END OF THIS PAGE)";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);
            List<string> cleaned = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value.Trim()).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It supports multi-line, understood - however, I have no idea how to tell it to extract the name/address lines.

Comment: @MatthewM. Fair enough, don't have time to think of the regex right now but can take a look later if needed.

Comment: Yes, ORIGNAL/BLANACE/PAST DUE are always there and will be in those positions.  I did not consider that I could use those, though I haven't done much with look ahead/behind.  I suppose the optional 3rd address line with no anchor could be anchored to "THIS IS THE END OF THIS PAGE" ?  Still, not sure on the specifics.

Comment: @MatthewM. If it gets you started I wrote a blog post that tries to explain lookaround - http://carndog.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/regex-string-splitting.html - it may get you started. The lookaround is in relation to the bracket characters ( and searches for the terms And or Or

Comment: You.. are.. awesome !  So - thank you so much.  I *just* completed my own version.. (\d{2}-\d-\d{5}-\d)|ORIGINAL\.{5}:\s+?(.*)$|(^\s{6}.*(?=ORIGINAL))|(\s{6}.*(?=BALANCE))|(\s{6}.*(?=PAST DUE))|(?:^\s{6}(.*)$(?=\n\n\THIS IS THE END OF THIS PAGE))? and am now going to compare the two.  Thank you for the pointers to lookahead/behind, etc.  I understand much better now and that in fact, was the key to understanding.  Your blog post and this page http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html were really helpful.

Comment: @MatthewM. Have updated my answer with the regex you wanted :)